# Write $x^4+x^2-2$ as multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$x^4+x^2-2$$

How do I write in a that can be used for partial fraction? taking out $x$ does not help, what is the process?

using Wolfram I got to $(x^2+2)(x-1)(x+1)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing a polynomial as the product of smaller multiplicative factors is called "factoring".

You might try the substitution $z = x^2$ to get $z^2 + z - 2$. Can you factor this polynomial?

Comment: sorry for using the wrong terms

Comment: @gbox No need for apologies. Just passing it along.

Answer (score 1):

Find the greatest common factor $k$ amongst the exponents of the nonzero powers of $x$ and perform a substitution of $y$ for $x^k$. Often, this substitution is the first step in seeing directly how to quickly factor a relatively simple polynomial into its irreducible parts, for, the polynomial in $y$, from the substitution, is of a lower or equal degree and as such may be easier to factor or to realize it has no factors.